# --banner-colour not working on fswebcam

Tags: camera, webcam, fswebcam

When I run `sudo fswebcam --png 9 -r 640x480 /var/www/image.jpg` on my raspberry pi, it works fine.

If I add `--banner-colour #ff0000` to it, like this:

`sudo fswebcam --banner-colour #ff0000 --png 9 -r 640x480 /var/www/image.jpg`

It tells me that my usage is wrong. Why is that argument not working?

Comment: Added the fswebcam tag - can you give a short description in the comments to add to the tag wiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `sudo` treats a plain `#` (hash or pound) character as a comment. You need to escape this character to make it work, like so `sudo fswebcam --banner-colour \#ff0000 --png 9 -r 640x480 /var/www/image.jpg`.

I have not tried this with `fswebcam`, but on my Ubuntu desktop I did the following tests:

```
$ sudo echo #ff0000

$ sudo echo "#ff0000"
#ff0000
$ sudo echo \#ff0000
#ff0000
$ sudo echo #;echo "hello"

$ _
```

Which seems to support my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Phil's solution worked for me. I wanted to change the line colour as well, so I used:

```
sudo fswebcam --banner-colour: \#000000 --line-colour \#ffffff --png 9 -r 640x480 /var/www/image.jpg
```

That worked fine on its own, but when I tried to combine it with `watch`, I was encountering the same error, despite the hashtags being escaped.

After some Googling, I was able to fix that problem by putting double quotes around all of the code that was being given to `watch`.

Here's the final code that I used:

```
watch -n10 "sudo fswebcam --banner-colour: \#000000 --line-colour \#ffffff --png 9 -r 640x480 /var/www/image.jpg"
```